# How to replace value of a column converted to day and month to a text using Python?

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

how do I achieve this in Python? Source file is a CSV file, and value of one column in that file is converted from numeric to day and month. Thank you very much in advance.

Example below:

Picture of the column:
[room column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPFSf.png)

In my python script, value should look below:

```
1-Feb ---> 2-1
2-Feb ---> 2-2
3-Mar ---> 3-3
4-Mar ---> 3-4
```

Here's my script.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory = 'C:/Path'
ext = ('.csv')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
f = os.path.join(directory, filename)

if f.endswith(ext):

    head_tail = os.path.split(f)
    head_tail1 = 'C:/Path'
    k =head_tail[1]
    r=k.split(".")[0]

    p=head_tail1 + "/" + r + " - Revised.csv"
    mydata = pd.read_csv(f)


    # to pull columns and values
    new = mydata[["A","Room","C","D"]]
    new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'Qty. of Parts'})
    new['Qty. of Parts'] = 1
    new.to_csv(p ,index=False)

    #to merge columns and values
    merge_columns = ['A', 'Room', 'C']
    merged_col = ''.join(merge_columns).replace('ARoomC', 'F')
    new[merged_col] = new[merge_columns].apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x), axis=1)

    new.drop(merge_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
    new = new.groupby(merged_col).count().reset_index()
    new.to_csv(p, index=False)
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of a CSV file ?

Comment: hello. the source file correct? I want to post it here but for security purposes I can't. My goal here is to replace the value in that column from 1-Feb ---> 2-1, 2-Feb ---> 2-2, 3-Mar ---> 3-3, 4-Mar ---> 3-4. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :

```
new["Room"]= (
                pd.to_datetime(new["Room"], format="%d-%b", errors="coerce")
                    .dt.strftime("%#m-%#d")
                    .fillna(new["Room"])
                )
```

Example :

```
     col
0  1-Feb
1  2-Feb
2  3-Mar
3    2-1
```

Gives :

```
   col
0  2-1
1  2-2
2  3-3
3  2-1
```

*NB: In case you're facing errors, you need to give a minimal reproducible example to show how look like your original (`.csv`) opened in a text editor and not in Excel.*

Comment: File "C:\MyProject.py", line 473, in _array_strptime_with_fallback
    result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 150, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: time data '2-1' does not match format '%d-%b' (match)
Question: Where should I insert your line to my script? @abokey, thank you

Comment: Can you try with `errors="ignore"`, answer updated.

Comment: File "C:\MyProject.py", line 512, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?

Comment: Ok it seems that you have mixed format in your column `Room`.  Check out the update I made to the answer ;)

Comment: This is where I inserted your line which still giving me errors: new = mydata[["A","Room","C","D"]]
        new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'Qty. of Parts'})
        new['Qty. of Parts'] = 1
        new["Room"] = (pd.to_datetime(new["Room"], format="%d-%b", errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%#m-%#d").fillna(new["Room"]))
        new.to_csv(p ,index=False)

Comment: Can you show which error ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyProject.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Room'

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyProject.py", line 42, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(new["Room"], format="%d-%b", errors="coerce")
  File "C:\MyProject.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\MyProject.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Room'

Comment: Can you put `print(new.columns)` after `new['Qty. of Parts'] = 1` and paste the result here ?

Comment: Your script works, sorry for the delay I had to extract data from different rooms and its is working as expected. Thank you very much for the assist! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the strings to dates to later get the values

```
import datetime
# datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 1, 0, 0)
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("1-Feb", "%d-%b")
print(f'{d.month}-{d.day}')
```

result:

```
2-1
```

Comment: Just to clarify the `strptime` parameters, the `%b` = Month as locale's abbreviated name, see all "Format Codes" here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Hi Diego thank you for the script and for the docs you shared. I'm trying to insert it in my script however im facing so many line errors :) Would you be so kind and tell me where should I put your script to mine? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not only 1-Feb ---> 2-1, 2-Feb ---> 2-2, 3-Mar ---> 3-3, 4-Mar ---> 3-4 has to be converted but any values with - from that column that is changed to a date format needs to be replaced by it's original text. If it's possible, I would really appreciate your input on this. Thank you so much.